# Парсинг страницы

Tags: android, html, java

Нужно с различных сайтов брать информацию, но вышло так, что именно та информация, которая нужна, не имеет RSS-ленты, также сайты не имеют API.

**Как будет проще получать информацию и выводить в Android:**

*- Делать запрос всей html-страницы, потом выбирать, откуда парсить информацию.*

*- Или же есть какие-то онлайн сервисы, которые отпарсят на своем сервере и вернут нужный блок, в котором информация для дальнейшего более точного парсинга?*

Answer (score 1):

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться.